# Pickling classes with circular reference behaves differently based on protocol

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pickle

If the `__qualname__` of a class is set to have a circular reference to itself, pickle behaves differently based on protocol. Following script demonstrates the issue:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import pickle, sys

class Foo:
    __name__ = __qualname__ = "Foo.ref"
    pass

Foo.ref = Foo

print(sys.version_info)

for proto in range(0, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL + 1):
    print("{}:".format(proto), end=" ")
    try:
        pkl = pickle.dumps(Foo, proto)
        print("Dump OK,", end=" ")
        assert(pickle.loads(pkl) is Foo)
        print("Load OK,")
    except Exception as err:
        print(repr(err))
```

**Output**

```
Python2.7:
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=16, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
0: Dump OK, Load OK,
1: Dump OK, Load OK,
2: Dump OK, Load OK,

Python3.7:
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
0: RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object')
1: RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object')
2: RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object')
3: RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object')
4: Dump OK, Load OK,
```

This was introduced as the side-effect of [commit](https://github.com/rsaim/cpython/commit/58e4134a1cf668a16006b896fca093d5a79966e3) to make "lookupable" objects (such as unbound methods) pickleable.

Please note that I have already opened an [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue38770?@ok_message=msg%20356388%20created%0Aissue%2038770%20created&@template=item) in Python bugs tracker. Posting this on StackOverflow to reach a wider audience. I have proposed the following three solutions to the issue.

1. Check if the class has a self-reference and raise an error for all protocols.
2. Use memoization to handle self-references. I am not sure what should be dumped in this case. In the example above `Foo` will exist in the namespace but not `Foo.ref`.
3. Dump such classes similar to Python 2 pickle and Python 3 pickle protocol >= 4.